# Why does adding a Table of Contents in Word with VBA not create a TOC object like it does when adding one manually?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Office 365; Word v. 2205

Why does adding a TOC with VBA (ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add) not produce the same robust TOC object that adding one manually does?

You will see in the first screenshot, a TOC that I added with VBA. The second screenshot is a TOC that I added manually. The manual TOC almost acts like a field object. It even comes with a title.

Is there a way to replicate the manual TOC but with VBA?

Here is my code:

```
Sub TOC()
    With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        .MoveStartUntil (Chr(13))
        .MoveStart Count:=1
        .TypeParagraph
        .MoveEnd Count:=-1
        .ClearFormatting
    End With
    
    Set oTOC = Selection.Range
    
    With ActiveDocument
        .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=oTOC
    End With
End Sub
```

---

#### *Screenshot 1:*

[image]

---

#### *Screenshot 2:*

[image]

Comment: If you record a macro when adding the TOC manually you will see that Word adds a building block that contains the TOC-fields ... if you want to replicate that you have to use that VBA code

Comment: MS has complicated TOC construction since the introduction of Word 2007 by wrapping Built-in TOCs in Building Blocks. The only potential advantage is that they include a 'Contents' title. The downside is that they impose a severe performance penalty when updating. The Built-in TOCs are no more or less robust than those created via TOC fields alone.

Comment: Macropod is correct. The TOC field without the Content Control is more responsive. If you insert a Custom TOC from the menu, you get the same unwrapped field. The same is true if you insert it from the Insert Field dialog.   ----   @Ike, It is not a building block, it is a Content Control that is inserted using a Building Block.

Comment: Additionally, the Building Block is lost if the document is subsequently saved in the .doc format.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Re: «It is not a building block, it is a Content Control that is inserted using a Building Block». I believe it isn't a content control, since content controls are converted to static text when a document containing them is saved in the .doc format. TOC fields and numerous other fields MS has deigned to embed in these structures don't suffer that fate.

Comment: Most of these things that look a bit like content contents but are not content controls are covered, to an extent, in the  .docx format standards in a section about SDT elements (Structured Data Tags). Content Controls are also represented using SDT elements. SDT is not a widely used term, presumably because it's not used in Word's UI, Help (AFAIK) or Object Model. One exception may be the control that displays when you insert a DATE field - looks similar but probably no SDT element in the XML.

Comment: The thing is, these controls whether called an SDT element (new one for me, I will try to remember it) or something else contain standard word fields. @Macropod The field is inside the container. When the container is nullified by saving in .doc format, the field (the contents of the container) remain. When the .doc formatted document is opened and saved back as a.docx file, the field remains but the container is not restored. The same thing happens if you put another field inside a Rich-Text CC and save in .doc format. The field is still there, just not the CC.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Regardless, these containers are *not* content controls - which is the point I was making. Further evidence of that is that they cannot be accessed via VBA code that processes content controls. MS is quite clear that all content inside a content control is converted to ***static text*** when a document is saved in the .doc format.

Comment: @macropod That is not what happens. Create a rich-text CC. Put a field in it, any field you want. Try one of your really complex date calculation fields! Save as a .doc format. The CC is gone. The field is there, not text.

Comment: SDT = "Structured Document Tag" not "Structured Data Tag" as I said earlier.  The section on SDTs in the standards document covers all SDT types (including TOC, Bibliography,  and Citation as well as the controls you can insert from the Developer tab). The term "content control" is not used at all in that document. Microsoft's documentation and the object model itself seem pretty clear that the Content Controls are the things listed in the WdContentControlType enumeration (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-content-controls )